# Put a new array in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Array that I want to put in another Array. I want it to look like this:

```
var myArray = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
```

The code that I use is:

```
var arrayOne = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
var myArray = [];
myArray.push([arrayOne[1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
myArray.push(arrayOne[1]);
```

because `arrayOne[1]` itself is an array, so there is no need to add it to another array.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m9CFX/)

Answer (score 0):

Typo

```
myArray.push(arrayOne[1]);   
             ^ removed ^ []
```

[.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

`arrayOne` don't wrap it in array as it already array .

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're saying that you want to copy all the elements in `arrayOne` into `myArray`. (Forgive me if I'm wrong...) In which case, you can combine [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(myArray, arrayOne);
```

This puts all the elements in `arrayOne` into `myArray`.